# Loading a 64-bit data into a 32-bit register

Tags: assembly, arm, keil, arm7

Let's say I have a 3-element array of 64-bit data:

```
   src    DCQ    0x0200200AD00236DD
          DCQ    0x00003401AAC4D097
          DCQ    0X0001FC219AC931BE
```

assuming that I know the address of "src" (named srcAdr), I can load the lower 32-bit content of an element of src at a certain index into a register named srcLo by saying:

```
   LDR    srcLo, [srcAdr, index, LSL#3]
```

In order to get the higher 32-bit content of this element, I know I can:

```
   ADD    srcAdrHi, srcAdr, #4
   LDR    srcHi, [srcAdrHi, index, LSL#3]
```

Question is, is there a more elegant way to do this? Say, for example, in one instruction?

Comment: What does the instruction set reference say (e.g. if you look up `LDRD`)?

Comment: Can't you do `ldr srcHi, [srcAdr, #4]`?

Comment: Thanks for your correspondence. I'm using ARM7TDMI, so it does not support LDRD.

Comment: use ldm instead of ldr

Comment: @fuz you definitely can, but I'm trying to adapt this scheme to an array of data rather than a single 64-bit piece of information, so having to incorporate index doesn't seem to work for 'ldr srcHi, [srcAdr, #4]'

Comment: you can do the add plus 4 as part of ldr,   ldr r0,[r1],#4 ; ldr r2,[r1] without the add

Comment: can also do the plus for as part of the load    ldr r0,[r3] ;  ldr r1,[r3,#4]

Comment: you have the arm documentation yes, processor documentation always required for assembly programming.    the armv5 arm arm covers the armv4t

Comment: ldmia r0,{r1,r2}  is one instruction r0 being the address

Comment: @JohnPark  I'm not sure what exactly you expect then.

Comment: Sorry guys. You're all coming up with really good solutions, but I left out a key detail, which is that I am working with an array of 64-bit data so I edited the question.

Comment: `working with an array of 64-bit data` - well, there are no "types" as far as CPU is concerned. If you insist on accessing 32-bit values using index values 0,1,2,... why make your own life harder by declaring these values with DCQ?  Anyway, I don't think you can do without an extra instruction here. If you write a test C snippet for a uint64_t array and compile you'll probably see the resulting assembly using `ldmia r0,{r1,r2}` as @old_timer suggested and r0 will be calculated according to the index (in a separate instruction).

Comment: you can load 64-bit data into **two 32-bit registers** but not ***a** 32-bit register*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment: I do not think you can do without an extra instruction here if for whatever reason you must work with the data as with a uint64_t array, using an index.

For a 'C' function:

```
int foo(unsigned long long *srcT, int index) {
  unsigned int temp=0;
  temp = (unsigned int)(srcT[index]);
  temp += (unsigned int)(srcT[index] >> 32);
  return temp;
}
```

The compiler (ARM gcc 8.2 -O3 -mcpu=arm7tdmi) produced:

```
foo:
    add     r3, r0, r1, lsl #3
    ldr     r3, [r3, #4]
    ldr     r0, [r0, r1, lsl #3]
    add     r0, r0, r3
    bx      lr
```

As you can see it also produced an extra instruction (`add`) to access the 'high half'.
The exact sequence of instructions would, of course, depend on what manipulations are performed on the array. If you'd walk through it in a loop you'd most likely get `ldm` + `add Rx,#8`, etc.